# Find equation for circle related to a triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry

write the equation of the circle of the triangle
with vertices $$A = (5 ,\ -4 ),\ B = (6 ,\ -1 ),\ C = ( 2,\ 3)$$
examine the relative position of this district and its image in axial symmetry about the line
$$3x + 4y + 26 = 0$$

I think about this: (drawing paper)[image]

Comment: Which "circle of the triangle" are you looking for? Inscribed circle? Circumcircle? Nine-point circle?

Comment: I searching described circle

Comment: x @Jon: "described circle" is not a standard term. Do you perhaps mean inscribed circle or circumscribed circle?

Comment: @Henning look in post.

Comment: That's a circumcircle, also known as a circumscribed circle.

Comment: Yes, you're right :)

Comment: Given any 3 points, the equation of a circle passing through that 3 points can be expressed as a determinant. For your case, $$\left|\begin{matrix}
x^2+y^2 & x & y & 1\\
5^2+(-4)^2 & 5 & -4 & 1\\
6^2+(-1)^2 & 6 & -1 & 1\\
2^2+3^2 & 2 & 3 & 1
\end{matrix}\right| = 0$$

Comment: How I can solve this matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $(A,B,C)$ into $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = R^2$ :
$$
(5-a)^2 + (-4-b)^2 = R^2 \\
(6-a)^2 + (-1-b)^2 = R^2 \\
(2-a)^2 + (3-b)^2 = R^2
$$ $$
a^2 - 10 a + 25 + b^2 + 8 b + 16 = R^2 \\
a^2 - 12 a + 36 + b^2 + 2 b + 1 = R^2 \\
a^2 - 4 a + 4 + b^2 - 6 b + 9 = R^2
$$
Subtract the second equation from the first one and the third equation from the second one:
$$
2 a - 11 + 6 b + 15 = 0 \\
- 8 a + 32 + 6 b - 3 = 0
$$ $$
2 a + 6 b = - 4 \\
- 8 a + 8 b = - 24
$$
Add the second equation to $4 \times$ the first one .. and do the rest:
$$
32 b = - 40 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad b = - 5/4 \\
2\cdot 2 a = - 8 + 15 = 7 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a = 7/4 \\
R^2 = (2-a)^2 + (3-b)^2 = 145/8
$$
So the circle is:
$$
(x-7/4)^2 + (y+5/4)^2 = \left(\sqrt{145/8}\right)^2
$$
[image]
Still don't know what you mean by "district" ..

Comment: Investigate the relative position of this circle and its image in the axial symmetry about the line 3x + 4y + 26 = 0

Comment: Onderzoeken de relatieve positie van de wijk en haar imago in axiale symmetrie over de lijn 3x + 4y + 26 =

Comment: Google translate my friend :)

Comment: @Jon.Don: Sure, so the translation is dreadful, which makes it even less comprehensible. English is not my problem, though. Manjana.

Comment: hm I have explored the relative position of this circle and its reflections in the axial symmetry about the line 3x+4y+26 = 0